# Python input in a middle of a message

Tags: python

Let’s say I have the code:

```
test = input(“What is your message?\n> ”)
print(test)
```

Output:

```
What is your message?
> Hi there!
Hi there!
```

Processed exited with code 0

But, is there a way in Python to make the user type an input in a middle of a message?
With the output:

```
Percent converter:
> 30%
```

I type: "30", not "30%". Is there a way to do that kind of thing in Python before I type an input? I also mean that I want to print the whole message but move my cursor back a few characters.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is it `f'{test}%'` ?

Comment: what do you mean by "input in a middle of a message"

Comment: I think he means that he'd like the prompt to be `> %` before the user types anything and for the user's typing to appear before the `%` as each key is pressed.

Comment: Seems like something you could do with `curses`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html

Comment: I think you should just interchange the order of input and print function.

Comment: I'm new to Python so I just simply need steps

Comment: I could use curses, but I am not sure which command to look for.

Answer (score 0):

```py
test = input("What is your message?\n>    %\b\b\b")
```

`\b` is the backspace character, so in this case it will print the message and move the cursor back 3 characters.

To answer you question below, you need to put the `\b` character at the end of the string, here's an example breaking down what is happening

```
input(">   ˚C\b\b\b\b")
# print ">   ˚C"
# move the cursor back 4 places
```

Comment: It worked, but I forgot to say that I want to add a message afterwards:
test = input("What is your message?\n>   %\b\b\b˚C")

I want the output to look like:
What is your message?
> ˚C

And that my cursor is between ">" and "˚C".

Comment: The output from the second section of code had this output:
> 

It didn't print out "˚C"

Code:
test = input(">   ˚C\b\b\b\b")

Comment: Are you copy + pasting or typing it in? [example on Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UnderstatedForsakenGzip)

Comment: Typing  in the middle of the print/input message

Comment: Try removing the degrees symbol `˚`, the terminal you're using might not support non-ascii symbols combined with the backspace character `\b`.

Comment: I did, still does not work. I also used it in other programs and it prints just fine.

Comment: One more thing, backspace seemed to delete instead of moving the cursor.